# What does the method ArrayUtils.newUnpaddedObjectArray() do?

Tags: java, android

When I read the source code of SparseArray in Android SDK, I met a method named ArrayUtils.newUnpaddedObjectArray(capacity). I don't understand what the unpadded array means?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information in class VMRuntime, which is used by class ArrayUtils.

The JavaDoc of VMRuntime.newUnpaddedArray(...) says:

> Returns an array of at least minLength, but potentially larger. The increased size comes from avoiding any padding after the array. The amount of padding varies depending on the componentType and the memory allocator implementation.

Java data types use different size in memory. If only the needed capacity would be allocated, some space at then end would be left unused before the next memory allocation. This space is called padding. So, in order to not waste this space, the array made a little bit larger.

Comment: I had read JavaDoc, but I can't understand what padding is? This is associated with JVM implementation, the smallest unit for memory allocation?

Comment: Padding is just the word for "filling space between objects". (No, it's not the smalles memory allocation unit.)